# Hash with array of values

Tags: ruby, hash

I am creating a hash which has a single key but an array of values associated with it.  I am trying to access a specific value in a specific index of the hash values array.

```
numbers = {fib => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]}
```

If I want to access index 3 then I would say numbers.values_at("numbers").index(4).  However, this does not return the value 5 but rather the entire array.  Is it possible to extract a single value from that hash's value array?

I am using ruby 1.9.3 so I can only use the methods found within this ruby version.

Comment: What do you mean by "access index 3 then ... index(4)"?

Comment: @ButtahNBred  I do not need answer as it is already answered but some extra info. It seems that you might be beginner in ruby, so some suggestion use REPL of ruby i.e interactive console by typing irb(on UNIX like os) in your terminal  to test any doubt. Believe me it will go long way to ease your pain. One more thing enclose <fib> in single quote or double, as what you wrote has syntax error if <fib> was not already declared before this . Also learn the difference between use of single quote and double quote.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
numbers[fib][i]
```

To access position i of the array.

The values_at method returns an array of values for when you pass multiple keys, if you only need a single value (thus only passing a single key to values_at) the proper way to do it would be to pass the key directly to the hash.

If you still want to access the hashes' value array, then you need to do something like this:

```
numbers.values_at(fib)[0][i]
```

Comment: Using `values_at` on a single value is really counter-productive and probably a really odd thing to do, especially since you un-do it in the next step. It's normally used for retrieving several keys simultaneously: `values_at(fib1, fib2, fib3)` and so on.

Comment: Exactly, just edited my original answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

numbers[fib][4] is the best way:

```
> numbers[fib]
=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> numbers[fib][4]
=> 5
```